# Bokeh - how to make heatmap fit content

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using a heatmap from the following example https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/unemployment.html

What's the easiest way to make it fit content? To be more precise I want the single cells to have specific width and height and the whole heatmap to adjust then to that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple or supported way to do that. You can specify a fixed size for the canvas, or specify that the canvas should stretch out scale to fit the available space on the page. There is no option to size the canvas based on the content inside.